# Place Ad after every third element - Laravel Foreach

Tags: html, css, laravel, foreach

I'm trying to change the design of my website but it doesn't work like I want it ( like allways ).

I want to place a full width div after every third element on my website.

Here is a picture like I how it looks now:

[image: Thats how it looks now]

And thats how I want it to be:

[image: Thats how I want it]

Thats my code:

```
@foreach($usergroups as $group)
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
            // Content of the black boxes
        </div>
        @if($counter % 3 == 0)
            <div class="col-md-12">
                // content of the red boxed ( Ad's by google )
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <?php $counter-- ?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy below styling in your css , This will align below marked elements to be in single row and then put fourth in the next row.

```
.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-4{

float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

amit "solution" is incorrect.

The problem is in your HTML. I assume you use bootstrap (based on CSS tags).

When your blade generates HTML it looks something like:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
        // Content of the black boxes
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        // content of the red boxed ( Ad's by google )
    </div>
</div>
```

This is wrong. Google ads box should be outside of the main div and all would work as expected.

So change your code to:

```
@foreach($usergroups as $group)
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo">
            // Content of the black boxes
        </div>
    </div>
    @if($counter % 3 == 0)
        <div class="col-md-12">
            // content of the red boxed ( Ad's by google )
        </div>
    @endif
    <?php $counter-- ?>
@endforeach
```

Take notice that red box div is outside.

And BTW you don't need counter. Laravel has `$loop` variable. See: [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable)